# Docker Compose 3 multiline

Tags: docker, docker-compose, yaml, docker-container

Why this is not working on docker compose version 3?

```
nginx:
   image: nginx
   container_name: nginx
   environment:
       VIRTUAL_HOST: > 
       proj1.local,proj2.local,
       proj3.local,proj4.local,proj5.local
```

I've a lot of virtual hosts and I need to go multilne but I receive:

```
ERROR: yaml.scanner.ScannerError: while scanning a simple key
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 31, column 7
could not find expected ':'
  in "./docker-compose.yml", line 32, column 7
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That isn't valid YAML. It looks like you haven't indented your YAML properly. The lines following the `>` indicator must be indented.

Comment: @jumpa . please validate with http://www.yamllint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tools such as [Yamllint](http://yamllint.com) are your friend when seeing those types of errors. That said, it sometimes doesn't give you a meaningful error when failing validation.

What you have in the example is an indentation problem. You should be using:

```
nginx:
  image: nginx
  container_name: nginx
  environment:
    VIRTUAL_HOST: > 
      proj1.local,proj2.local,
      proj3.local,proj4.local,proj5.local
```

Which will translate into:

```
nginx: 
  container_name: nginx
  environment: 
    VIRTUAL_HOST: "proj1.local,proj2.local, proj3.local,proj4.local,proj5.local"
  image: nginx
```